# I can't get specific row's postition in table using order by in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want to get position of specific row in MySQL table using operation 'order by'.
Let's say i have this table:

[image]

And now i want to order them by user_points (ascending) and get Ann's position in here. The output I desire is '3'. I was trying to do it, but with no results... If anyone has any idea how to do it I'd be grateful.

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: xampp, it is 10.4.11-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is:

```
select count(*) + 1
from t
where t.user_points < (select t2.user_points
                       from t t2
                       where t2.name = 'Ann'
                      );
```

This is equivalent to the window function `rank()`:

```
select t.*, rnk
from (select t.*, rank() over (order by score) as rnk
      from t
     ) t
where name = 'Ann';
```

But with the right indexes, the first version might be a little bit faster.

Comment: I'll check it and give feedback :D